# moore neighbourhood code to find number of neighbour cells with 1s

Tags: function, python-3.x, neighbours

guys im given a task where i have to find the number of 1s around a cell in a grid.[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plWdg.png) from the example figure i should get 3 since there are 3 1s around the cell. so i did the code and i got it right but when i used a function to do the same code its giving me errors and i need your help.

```
def count_neighbours(((1, 0, 0, 1, 0),(0, 1, 0, 0, 0),(0, 0, 1, 0, 1),(1, 0, 0, 0, 0),(0, 0, 1, 0, 0),), 1, 2):
grid=count_neighbours[0]
row=count_neighbours[1]
col=count_neighbours[2]
length=len(grid)
s=0
d=0
for i in range(row-1,row+2):
    for j in range(col-1,col+2):
        if i>=0 and j>=0:
            if i<=length-1 and j<=length-1:
                if grid[i][j]==1:
                    s+=1
if grid[row][col]==1:
    d+=1
total = s-d
return total
#error goes like this
def count_neighbours(((1, 0, 0, 1, 0),(0, 1, 0, 0, 0),(0, 0, 1, 0, 1),(1, 0, 0, 0, 0),(0, 0, 1, 0, 0),), 1, 2):
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look into the basics of the function definition in python. You should not put the input values in the function definition.

I feel this is what you are looking for.

```
def count_neighbours(inputgrid):
    grid=inputgrid[0]
    row=inputgrid[1]
    col=inputgrid[2]
    length=len(grid)
    s=0
    d=0
    for i in range(row-1,row+2):
        for j in range(col-1,col+2):
            if i>=0 and j>=0:
                if i<=length-1 and j<=length-1:
                    if grid[i][j]==1:
                        s+=1
    if grid[row][col]==1:
        d+=1
    total = s-d
    print (total)
    return total


count_neighbours((((1, 0, 0, 1, 0),(0, 1, 0, 0, 0),(0, 0, 1, 0, 1),(1, 0, 0, 0, 0),(0, 0, 1, 0, 0),), 1, 2))
```